# How to solve this iText PDF error?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I'm merging two pdf pages (test1.pdf & test2.pdf) using iText PDF and got the output in test_result.pdf. But the output page has not come out like the input page, it's cropped to half of the actual size. How to overcome this error? Here is my code:

```
public class MergePDF {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        List<InputStream> pdfs = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
        pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("test1.pdf"));
        pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("test2.pdf/"));
      //  pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("test_result.pdf/"));
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/home/ant000112/merge_result.pdf");
        MergePDF.concatPDFs(pdfs, output, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void concatPDFs(List<InputStream> streamOfPDFFiles,
        OutputStream outputStream, boolean paginate) {

    Document document = new Document();
    try {
        List<InputStream> pdfs = streamOfPDFFiles;
        List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
        int totalPages = 0;
        Iterator<InputStream> iteratorPDFs = pdfs.iterator();

        // Create Readers for the pdfs.
        while (iteratorPDFs.hasNext()) {
            InputStream pdf = iteratorPDFs.next();
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
            readers.add(pdfReader);
            totalPages += pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
        }
        // Create a writer for the outputstream
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);

        document.open();
        //BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,BaseFont.CP1257, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); // Holds the PDF
        // data
        PdfImportedPage page;
        int currentPageNumber = 0;
        int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
        Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

        // Loop through the PDF files and add to the output.
        while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
            PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();
            // Create a new page in the target for each source page.
            while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
                document.newPage();
                pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
                currentPageNumber++;
                page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader,
                        pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
                cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                // Code for pagination.
                if (paginate) {
                    cb.beginText();
                    cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
                    cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, ""+ currentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages, 520,5, 0);
                    cb.endText();
                }
            }
            pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (document.isOpen())
            document.close();
        System.out.println("ghghklh");
        try {
            if (outputStream != null)
                outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try reading examples from the iText site? It appears you're doing it in a different way. Like you're not using `PdfCopy`.

```
/*
 * This class is part of the book "iText in Action - 2nd Edition"
 * written by Bruno Lowagie (ISBN: 9781935182610)
 * For more info, go to: http://itextpdf.com/examples/
 * This example only works with the AGPL version of iText.
 */

package part2.chapter06;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;

import part1.chapter02.MovieHistory;
import part1.chapter02.MovieLinks1;

public class Concatenate {

    /** The resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String RESULT
        = "results/part2/chapter06/concatenated.pdf";

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException 
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, DocumentException, SQLException {
        // using previous examples to create PDFs
        MovieLinks1.main(args);
        MovieHistory.main(args);
        String[] files = { MovieLinks1.RESULT, MovieHistory.RESULT };
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        PdfReader reader;
        int n;
        // loop over the documents you want to concatenate
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            reader = new PdfReader(files[i]);
            // loop over the pages in that document
            n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
            }
            copy.freeReader(reader);
        }
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }
}
```

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=123

**EDIT:** Just to be fair I downloaded the library and I tried the example. It works like a charm.

Comment: i'm asking about merging of two different pdf files into a single pdf

Comment: yeah, the example is called part2.chapter06.Concatenate. It takes a bunch of files then loops over every page of every document. The final file is handled by PdfCopy

Comment: But the extracted pages are cropped to half of it's original size which gave as an input.

Comment: Yes there is: String[] files = { MovieLinks1.RESULT, MovieHistory.RESULT }; these are the path of the two files he's using. Then it just acquires the files with PdfReader. It's really not that different from yours, actually.

Comment: @mojmaho it's not my code, it's from their tutorials. Please check you're using right paths.